# Threading and synchronisation in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

If there is a synchronized method in a class and 1 thread enters it, can another thread call the same method on a different object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, if the method is not `static`.

A `synchronized` non-static method synchronizes on `this`. So this method:

```
public synchronized void foo() {
  // do stuff
}
```

is effectively equivalent to this one:

```
public void foo() {
  synchronized(this) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

A `static`synchronized method synchronizes on the current class. So a method like this:

```
public static synchronized void bar() {
  // do stuff
}
```

is effectively equivalent to this one:

```
public static void bar() {
  synchronized(ThisClass.class) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a bit missleading, classes sharing the same reference doesn't require the methods to be `static`.

Comment: @Johan: a "synchronized method" usually implies a method that uses the `synchronized` keyword in its declaration (and not inside the method body). That means that they do in fact synchronize on difference objects.

Answer (score 3):

If the method is marked as `synchronized`, then the lock is held on the object. This means that a call to the same method on a different object will not be locked.
However, if the method is a `static` one, then it is held by the entire class and it will not be possible for a second call to run it at the same time [and will be blocked]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, another thread can call this method from instance of this class